# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, delete whitespaces from a string method

Tags: java, string, swing, stringbuilder

I'm making a cryptography/cryptanalysis program using java as a homework for my master. Anyway, i use a method to delete the uselless whitespaces and make the String i display to the JTextArea proper. This method is great for small texts but it gives me a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when i use bigger texts (loaded from a .txt file). Can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance.

This is the method:

```
public void Data(String s) {
    System.out.print("Analysis" + "\n" + s);
    jTextArea1.setText(s);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
            buf.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) &&   !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
            buf.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(buf.toString() + "\n" + "from buf");
    jTextArea1.setText(buf.toString());
}
```

Comment: you read `s.charAt(i + 1)`, so if the last character in the string is a whitespace, you will get out of bounds error. You can't read `s.charAt(i + 1)` if `i + 1 == s.length()`, which it will in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going up to `s.length()` in the for loop but accessing `s.charAt(i + 1)` in the second if statement. Try to only go up to `s.length() - 1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        buf.append(s.charAt(i));
    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) &&   !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
        buf.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

And then check the last character afterwards.

Comment: it's just the problem of loosing the last character of the string. :S

Comment: i am adding the last character manually. meaning:
        buf.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));

Answer (score 1):

`s.charAt(i + 1)` in `!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i + 1))`

It fails when `i == s.length() - 1`

You might want to use `s.replaceAll("\\s\\s+"," ")` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Just "\\s+" in the origin string is enough. I might additionally trim the string to get rid of single leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @JuhaLaiho: true. but it might be more expansive since more strings will have to be replaced: you will also have to replace one space for another one whitespace string. the jvm/compiler might optimize it and ignore these cases - but I am not sure at all this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this statement

```
Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i + 1)
```

meaning you are accessing an character of your string length plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
hi i hope you can use the below one, instead the above

//StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
/*  These lines are not needed 
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
            buf.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) &&   !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i + 1))) {
            buf.append(s.charAt(i));
        }`enter code here`
    }
*/
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
// Whenever you print the object(reference) toString() method is called by default. so no need to call explicitly
//    System.out.println(buf.toString() + "\n" + "from s");
    System.out.println(s + "\n" + "from buf");
//    jTextArea1.setText(s);
    jTextArea1.setText(s);
```

Comment: this is a solution. but i think i'll loose the \n characters.